# Convert list of tuples to array without using numpy

Tags: python, arrays

I have a list of tuples,

```
[(100, 'Steven', 'King'), (101, 'Brown', 'White'), (102, 'Will', 'Martin')]
```

Am expecting to convert it to an array as below,

```
    [100, 'Steven', 'King' 
    101, 'Brown', 'White' 
    102, 'Will', 'Martin']
```

It is possible using numpy, but am trying to do it in python itself without using any library.
Any suggestion will be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Will `[j for i in a for j in i]` (with `a` being your array) do the job, or can there be differently nested expressions?